# how to properly expand filenames in zsh alias

Tags: zsh

Wrote a seemingly simple alias to convert mp3 to wav but doesn't expand the files at run time.  Changed it to a function after I was unable to get it working.

Was hoping to get an explanation of why it didn't work as written.

> alias 2wav="for fn in *.mp3;do echo \"Converting $fn\";avconv -y -i $fn ${$(basename $fn .mp3)}.wav 2>/dev/null;done"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

alias 2wav='for fn in *.mp3;do echo "Converting ${fn}";avconv -y -i "${fn}" "${$(basename "${fn}" .mp3)}".wav 2>/dev/null;done'

Now works for filenames containing spaces.  I'm guessing that the single quotes prevent the expansion from happening until runtime and that's why this works.

Any clarification is welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Do any of your filenames contain spaces? e.g. `foo bar.mp3` would produce a command line of

```
avconv -y -i foo bar.mp3 foo bar.wav
             ^^^---input file, doesn't exist
                 ^^^^^^^--output file, but since there's no input, it's useless
                         ^^^^^^^^^^--- miscellaneous unknown/invalid arguments
```

You'd need quotes around the arguments:

```
alias ........ -y -i "$fn" "${$(basename .....}".wav
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved (at least partially).

alias 2wav='for fn in *.mp3;do echo "Converting ${fn}";avconv -y -i ${fn} ${$(basename ${fn} .mp3)}.wav 2>/dev/null;done'

Not sure why this fixed it but I enclosed the command with single quotes and added braces around the vars and it just worked.  True that spaces in file names would still be a potential problem.  I'll have to experiment with that.